# mysql_fetch_array in PDO

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo, fetch

I changed my connection to PDO

```
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOSTINT.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAMEINT, DBUSERINT, DBPASSINT);
```

I have the following code in the old "mysql_query"

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   echo '<div class="cuisine-detail">'. $row["text"]. '</div>';
   echo '</div>';

}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

How I can transform this to the PDO way :

Answer (score 0):

Check docs: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM menu';
foreach ($DB->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<div class="cuisine-detail">'. $row["text"]. '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For more complex queries better use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php